# SQL query for object with specific entries on a join table

Tags: sql, inner-join, join

I have a join table with the following columns:

```
target_id
assoc_id
int_attr
```

They represent my target object, its associated object, and an integer attribute that describes the association.

I am given a hash with keys representing the association attribute and values which contain the associated id with that attribute.  For example:

```
{
  1: [3, 5],
  2: [7, 9],
}
```

I am trying to develop an SQL query which finds all target_ids with the appropriate join table entries.  In the example above, it would find any target object with the 4 entries:

```
`targets_assocs`
target_id assoc_id int_attr
X         3        1
X         5        1
X         7        2
X         9        2
A         3        1
A         5        1
A         7        2
A         9        2
C         2        1
C         4        1
C         6        2
C         8        2
```

In this case, it would return X and A, ignoring, C.

I was trying to use some type of HAVING clause.  I am trying to avoid having multiple nested subqueries using IF EXISTS.  Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I really have not written requests for MySQL, sorry for typos.

```
SELECT `target_id` FROM (
   SELECT `target_id`, count(*) FROM (
      SELECT `targets`.`target_id`, `targets_assocs`.`int_attr` FROM `targets`
       INNER JOIN `targets_assocs` ON `targets_assocs`.`target_id` = `targets`.`id`
       GROUP BY `targets`.`target_id`, `targets_assocs`.`int_attr`
   ) 
   GROUP BY `target_id`
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think perhaps I worded the question poorly, I updated it for more clarification.

Comment: Thanks again for your time.  By adding WHERE clauses to the inner most SELECT statement, I was able to accomplish what I was looking for in a finite number of select statements.  Much appreciated.